# How to query heroku database from salesforce (eg. via vf page)

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres

can anyone help me on this? How can I achieve the following:

I need to set up a prototype integration with heroku from salesforce application. The need is to store a huge volume of data in a single heroku table and accessble from salesforce - eg: have a vf page in salesforce which queries the data in realtime

Answer (score 1):

We're doing this. We use Heroku connect. We created a salesforce custom object and bidirectionally synched it using Heroku connect. You can then update the data on either side (in salesforce or in Heroku:PG).

But Heroku connect is expensive & priced on a # of synchs per month.

https://www.heroku.com/connect

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, heroku is not a database. It is a PAAS.

My approach would have been : 
- Create  a heroku app(this is a link to create a node.js app) [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) 
- After you create the app choose one of the datastore addons -> [link](https://addons.heroku.com/) if you want a SQL/Column oriented Database choose heroku postgres or ClearDB Mysql
- Secondly you actually need a webserver that exposes this database to you. I am thinking you would make this a webservice of some sort. You can build that in node.js. Here is something that will get you started or give you an idea - [link](http://dailyjs.com/2011/09/26/heroku/)